# how to get value from python and show in webpage using php

Tags: python, php, html, postgresql

I have a PHP file called display.php and a python file giveDATA.py.

from giveDATA.py, this is output: (77, '8088800000')

I would like to capture this output in separate variables in PHP and print one by one on a webpage.

1) display.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $command = escapeshellcmd('C:/guna/python/giveDATA.py');
    $x = shell_exec($command);
    echo "<pre>$x</pre>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

2) giveDATA.py
In my python file I am getting values from a table:

```
    results=cursor.fetchall()

            for x in results:
                print(x)
            connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell does not know that you want to run a script because you`re just giving it a path. Replace this:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('C:/guna/python/giveDATA.py');
```

With this:

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 C:/guna/python/giveDATA.py');
```

Comment: I am able to run the php code and I can see this output in the webpage. How to display this output line by line.(77, '8088800000')